# Redirect retaining the query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect a user retaining the query string?

**example 1:**

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/welcome.html?abc=123
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/welcomeNew.html?abc=123
```

**example 2:**

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/welcome.html?xyz=321
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/welcomeNew.html?xyz=321
```

I tried this and does not work?

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^pages/welcome.html?([a-z0-9]*)$ www.mydomain.com/pages/welcomeNew.html?$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `?` at all. The query string is automatically retained:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/welcome.html$ /pages/welcomeNew.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Does not work. My code was working before but not any more. Any ideas? it is not redirecting at all.